# Proving $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is a $C^{1}$ function and that $D_{12}f(0,0)$ is not $D_{22}f(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**
> Define $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by:
> $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $0 \text{ for } (x,y) = (0,0)$. Prove that $f$ is a $C^{1}$ function but that $D_{12}f(0,0) \neq D_{21}f(0,0)$. Show that $D_{12}f$ and $D_{21}f$ are not continuous in $(0,0)$

**My attempt:**
To prove that $f$ is a $C^{1}$ function, we need to prove that the both partial derivatives are continuous at the origin.

$$
f_{x} = \frac{(x^{2}+y^{2})y^{3} - 2x^{2}y^{3}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}} \leq \frac{(x^{2}+y^{2})y^{3}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}} = \frac{y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq y^{3} \leq \delta^{3}
$$

So $f_{x}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Analogue for $f_{y}$.

I would not know how to prove the second part. Am I supposed to just calculate $D_{12}f = f_{xy}$ and $D_{21}f = f_{yx}$ and show from different angles that the limit is different.

Comment: You cannot compute the second derivatives and then take a limit, because it will not be continuous at $(0,0)$. You have to take the derivative from definition. Speaking of, you haven't actually proven the first derivatives were continuous at $(0,0)$ yet, because you never computed $f_x(0,0)$, and so on.